# Handling HTTP Errors inside services

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

I'm learning Nest, but there is a practice that i don't really like even in the official tutorial. It's one of Handling HTTP specific errors inside services. If later, for some services i'll used a protocol other that HTTP that will use a Service that handle specific HTTP errors, it don't think it's a best practice. As I'm not yet a Nestjs expert, here is how i'm trying to handle this situation:

```
// errors.interface.ts
export interface IError {
  errorCode: number;
  errorMessage: string;
}
```

````
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { IError } from './errors.interface';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  // ...
  async remove(id: number): Promise<Partial<User> | IError> {
    const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({ where: { id } });
    if (!user) {
      return { errorCode: 404, errorMessage: 'user not found' };
    }
    await this.userRepository.remove(user);
    return {
      id,
    };
  }
}```

Here is my controller.

```// user.controller.ts
import { Controller, Get, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { IError } from './errors.interface';

@Controller('users')
export class UserController {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  @Get(':id')
  async remove(@Param('id') id: number) {
    const result = await this.userService.remove(id);
    if ('errorCode' in result) {
      throw new HttpException(result.errorMessage, result.errorCode);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
````

As you can see, I'm trying to handle HTTP-specific errors inside HTTP controllers.

I don't have enough experience with `Nestjs`, maybe there are better ways to tackle these kinds of problems. I would like to know what is the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

> To create a Nest application instance, we use the core NestFactory class. NestFactory exposes a few static methods that allow creating an application instance. The create() method returns an application object, which fulfills the INestApplication interface. This object provides a set of methods which are described in the coming chapters. In the main.ts example above, **we simply start up our HTTP listener, which lets the application await inbound HTTP requests.**

so you can only work with HTTP requests and handling HTTP specific errors inside services is in fact the best practice.